# Loaded scene element isn't fully displayed

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

**Summary**
I'm creating a menu for Hololens app. Following the documentation it has to be split in 3 parts:

1. an empty scene
2. a menu scene
3. a random scene

The empty scene is the one defined in MRTK Scene System so it will always be displayed. This one has to be empty and load the menu scene.

**The problem**
The app start, the empty scene load the menu scene but I only find the back plate and the text I put on the back of the plate. The buttons can't be found anywhere. Here are some pictures [from Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTcXs.jpg)

**What I've tried**
Following this sample [from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples) I added the following script in my empty scene :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool IsFirstLoad = true;
    private void Start()
    {
        if (IsFirstLoad)
        {
            IsFirstLoad = false;
            CoreServices.SceneSystem.LoadContent("menu", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }
}
```

and I created my `menu` scene like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cc3f.jpg). I took the same settings as the sample for the position of the buttons and the back plate, when I launch the sample it's working but on my app I can't figure out where are the buttons

[EDIT] to debug I even added a cube which is visible, but I can't find my buttons [as you can see on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQtEK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult for me to check the issue from the screenshots you provided. Would you also try to reproduce this issue with **prefabs** provided by MRTK? Please refer to [Buttons - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/button?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) and [Near menu - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/near-menu?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) to start using these prefabs.

Comment: I was missing a script which is present in the samples called  `OpenBaseSceneAdditively` which solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new scene for menu and set that as start scene in the project settings or else by default it will not show, because when the game starts it needs a scene to display.

Comment: Following the sample I created an empty scene which load the menu (and as you can see on the picture the menu is loaded) but for a reason the buttons aren't showing https://imgur.com/a/c3TCz2j

Comment: look at my edit maybe you can spot what I'm doing wrong